# Find the position of a string in an array in Bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm writing a shell script, and I have created an array containing several strings:

```
array=('string1' 'string2' ... 'stringN')
```

Now, I have a string saved in a variable, say a:

```
a='stringM'
```

And this string is part of the array.
My question is: how do I find the position of the string in the array, *without having to check the terms one by one with a **for** loop*?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The basic question is: ***why* do you want to avoid a `for` loop?**

- **Syntactical convenience and expressiveness**: you want a more elegant way to conduct your search.
- **Performance**: you're looking for the fastest way to conduct your search.

**tl;dr**

**For performance reasons, prefer *external-utility* solutions to *pure shell* approaches**; fortunately, **external-utility solutions are often also the more expressive solutions**:

- For *large* element counts, they will be much faster.
- While they will be slower for *small* element counts, the *absolute* time spent executing will still be low overall.

---

The following snippet shows you **how these two goals intersect** (note that both commands return the *1*-based index of the item found; assumes that the array elements have no *embedded* newlines):

```
# Sample input array - adjust the number to experiment
array=( {1..300} )

# Look for the next-to-last item
itmToFind=${array[@]: -1}

# Bash `for` loop
i=1
time for a in "${array[@]}"; do
    [[ $a == "$itmToFind" ]] && { echo "$i"; break; }
    (( ++i ))
done

# Alternative approach: use external utility `grep`
IFS=$'\n' # make sure that "${array[*]}" expands to \n-separated elements
time grep -m1 -Fxn "$itmToFind" <<<"${array[*]}" | cut -d: -f1
```

`grep`'s `-m1` option means that at most *one* match is searched for; `-Fnx` means that the search term should be treated as a *literal* (`-F`), match *exactly* (the full line, `-x`), and prefix each match with its *line number* (`-n`).

With the array size given - `300` *on my machine* - the above commands perform about the same:

```
300

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s

300

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s
```

*The specific threshold will vary*, but:

- Generally speaking, the higher the element count, the faster a solution based on an *external utility* such as `grep` will be.
- For *low* element counts, the *absolute* time spent will probably not matter much, even if the external utility solution is comparatively slower.

To show one end of the extreme, here are the timings for a `1,000,000`-element array (1 million elements):

```
1000000

real    0m13.861s
user    0m13.180s
sys 0m0.357s

1000000

real    0m1.520s
user    0m1.411s
sys 0m0.005s
```

Answer (score 1):

without any other information on array there is no other solution than check each element, if data is sorted a search by dichotomy can be done.
otherwise another structure can be used like a hash.

for example instead of elements appending to array since bash 4.

```
declare -A hash
i=0;
for str in string{A..Z}; do
    hash[$str]=$((i++))
done

echo "${hash['stringI']}"
```

Comment: Too bad... Thank you for answering so quickly anyway

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you or if this is the best way to do it avoiding a **for** loop, but you can try:

```
$ array=('string1' 'string2' 'string3' 'string4')
$ a='string3'
$ printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -m1 -Fxn "$a" | cut -d: -f1
3
$ i=$(( $(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -m1 -Fxn "$a" | cut -d: -f1) - 1 ))
$ echo $i
2
```

Breaking it down:

```
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

prints every element of the array separated by a new line, then we pipe it to `grep` to get the matching line number for the `$a` variable and use `cut` to get only the line number wihtout the match:

```
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -m1 -Fxn "$a" | cut -d: -f1
```

Finally, substract `1` from the matching line number returned using [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) and store it in `$i`:

```
i=$(( $(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -m1 -Fxn "$a" | cut -d: -f1) - 1 ))
```

Comment: @KCJV Glad it works for you, I edited my answer to add an explanation as it might be useful.

Comment: That's just the same as looping by hand, except that it's `sed` that does the looping over it's input. Possibly slower because of the fork+exec, at least for small arrays

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, the question said "without having to check the terms one by one with a **for** loop". My answer is not using a **for** loop. As far as speed, I thing is going to be much faster for large arrays than using a **for** loop, for small ones the speed difference might be neglectable, but those are just speculations.

Comment: ++for a promising approach overall, but `sed` is the wrong tool for the job: even if you _anchored_ the search term with `sed -n "/^$a\$/="`, you'd still run into problems if `$a` happened to contain _regex metacharacters_. You really want _literal_, _full-line_ matching in this case.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the feedback, you are right. Updated my answer to use the `grep` + `cut` aproach.

Answer (score 0):

As others have shown way based on current array, may I suggest you could also turn the array into an associative one and have your strings as the indexes pointing to numbers.

```
declare -A array=(['string1']=1
                  ['string2']=2
                  ...
                  ['stringN']=N )

a='stringM'

echo ${array[$a]}
```